# Ownership and permissions for nginx local webserver

Tags: php, nginx, permissions

I'm having trouble setting up my local nginx environment. I've been reading countless tutorials online and everything seems to have jumbled my brain a little.

OS: OSX 10.11.4 El Capitan
Nginx: 1.8.1
PHP-FPM: 5.5.31

My web root's file directory is as follows for now:

```
/webserver
/webverver/phpinfo.php
/webserver/example
/webserver/example/index.php
```

I can access the default "Welcome to Nginx" page using curl or in a web browser accessing localhost. If I then browse I get the indexing of files, yet the PHP files will attempt to download rather than execute. If I try to access the example site that I have created at `local.example.com` (which I have added to my hosts file) then I get 403 Forbidden header return using curl and a nice, simple 'Access Denied' using the web browser.

I'm not so clued up on file permissions and directory ownership, could someone advise as to how I should be configuring everything? I was advised to run the following command, but it changed nothing as of yet:

`sudo chmod -R 755 /Users/nickcorin/webserver`

There aren't any logs in my error log besides 'signal started' logs.

Here's my configuration at the moment:

`nginx.conf`

```
#user nobody;
worker_processes  1;

error_log  logs/error.log;
error_log  logs/error.log  notice;
error_log  logs/error.log  info;

#pid        logs/nginx.pid;


events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}


http {
    include       mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                      '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                      '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    access_log  logs/access.log  main;

    sendfile        on;
    tcp_nopush     on;

    keepalive_timeout  65;

    #gzip  on;

    server {
        listen       80;
        server_name  localhost;

        location / {
            root   /Users/nickcorin/webserver;
        autoindex on;
        }

        # redirect server error pages to the static page /50x.html
        #
        error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
        location = /50x.html {
            root   html;
        }
    }

    include servers/*;
}
```

`servers/example`

```
upstream php {
    server 127.0.0.1:9000;
}

server {
    listen 80;

    root /Users/nickcorin/webserver/example;
    server_name local.example.com;

    index index.php index.html index.htm;
    autoindex on;

     location ~ \.php$ {
            try_files  $uri  $uri/  /index.php?$args ;
            index  index.html index.htm index.php;
            fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_path_info;
            fastcgi_param PATH_TRANSLATED $document_root$fastcgi_path_info;
            fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;

            fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
            fastcgi_index index.php;
            fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
            fastcgi_intercept_errors on;
            include fastcgi_params;
        }
}
```

** EDIT - NGINX Folder Permissions & Process Owners **

I ran `ls -la` on my log folder `/usr/local/var/nginx` and this was the result:

```
drwxr-xr-x  4 nickcorin  admin   136 Apr 20 23:53 .
drwxr-xr-x  5 nickcorin  admin   170 Apr 20 21:47 ..
-rw-r--r--  1 root       admin  4718 Apr 21 08:06 access.log
-rw-r--r--  1 nickcorin  admin   480 Apr 21 10:28 error.log
```

And this was the result on my webserver root:

```
drwxr-xr-x   4 nickcorin  staff   136 Apr 22 12:23 .
drwx-----x+ 54 nickcorin  staff  1836 Apr 22 10:01 ..
drwxr-xr-x   3 nickcorin  staff   102 Apr 20 22:14 example
-rw-r--r--@  1 nickcorin  staff    23 Apr 19 11:58 info.php
```

This was the result of `ps aux | grep nginx`:

```
root              756   0.0  0.0  2466616    480   ??  Ss   12:24PM   0:00.00 nginx: master process nginx
nickcorin         759   0.0  0.0  2445080    820 s000  S+   12:24PM   0:00.00 grep nginx
nobody            757   0.0  0.0  2475832   1044   ??  S    12:24PM   0:00.00 nginx: worker process
```

** EDIT #2 - Virtual Host Config File **

I managed to fix my problem and things seem to be working smoothly now. I had to edit my Virtual Host configuration file to this:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80 ipv6only=on;

    server_name local.example.com;

    root /Users/nickcorin/webserver/example;
    index index.php index.html index.htm;

    location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files $uri =404;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }
}
```

I also fixed my permissions with the following two lines:

```
sudo chown -R nickcorin /Users/nickcorin/webserver (Web Server Root)
sudo chmod 755 /Users/nickcorin/webserver/example (Virtual Host Root)
```

Thank you to everyone that helped me figure this out :)

Comment: Does **user** and **group** in your php-fpm pool matches user/group owner of your web files?

Comment: You've opened up a new thought entirely, I'm very new to nginx, I wasn't aware that I had to do something like that? I just left everything with php-fpm default? `ps aux | grep php-fpm` shows that my user 'nickcorin' handles the processes.

Comment: `ps aux | grep php-fpm` indicates `listen.owner` and `listen.group` attributes in php-fpm's pool configuration. Make sure `user` and `group` in the pool configuration matches your files permissions. Edit the default pool configuration ex: `/etc/php5/fpm/pool.d/www.conf` or copy it to a new pool like `/etc/php5/fpm/pool.d/mysite.conf` and make it to listen in another port by `listen = 127.0.0.1:9001`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue I had was the configuration file for my virtual host and the permissions with my webserver root. These are my current, working configuration settings for anybody else struggling with similar problems:

`nginx.conf`

```
user yourusername staff;
worker_processes  1;

error_log  logs/error.log;
error_log   logs/error.log warn;
error_log  logs/error.log  notice;
error_log  logs/error.log  info;

#pid        logs/nginx.pid;


events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}


http {
    include       mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                      '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                      '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    access_log  logs/access.log  main;

    sendfile        on;
    tcp_nopush     on;

    keepalive_timeout  65;

    #gzip  on;

    server {
        listen       80;
        server_name  localhost;

        location / {
            root   /Users/yourusername/webserver;
            autoindex on;
        }

        # redirect server error pages to the static page /50x.html
        #
        error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
        location = /50x.html {
            root   html;
        }
    }

    include servers/*;
}
```

`servers/example`

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80 ipv6only=on;

    server_name local.example.com;

    root /Users/yourusername/webserver/example;
    index index.php index.html index.htm;

    location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files $uri =404;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }
}
```

Once these were set up properly, I then ran these commands to fix my permission errors in the webserver:

```
sudo chown -R yourusername /Users/yourusername/webserver
sudo chmod 755 /Users/yourusername/webserver/example
```

Don't forget to add `127.0.0.1        local.example.com` into your hosts file.

Answer (score 3):

**Checklist for the case:**

1. Ensure that 403 Forbidden caused by web server, not application scripts. For example make index.php looks like

```php
echo 'hi there';
```

If the error still exists, then probably we have misconfigurated web server.

2. Find out a reason of permission denied error, generated by web server. You can temporarly add this directive to your servers/example config (maybe right after server_name):

```
error_log /var/log/nginx/example.error.log warn
```

or even so

```
error_log /var/log/nginx/example.error.log notice
```

But according to your nginx.conf you're already done that, so check the log-file to find information about permissions related troubles.

Normally you should find there concrete description of problem - files invalid permission, socket invalid permissions or upstream troubles.

3. Fix the error. This generally depends on what we had found on previous step.

a. Wrong permissions for files hosted on web server.

1) Who is who - determ web server user (`nginx` by default) and owner and group for the site directory (/Users/nickcorin/webserver/example). Each parent directory (itself) should be (at least) executable (--x) for `nginx` user (Users, nickcorin, and webserver).

2) While the `example` dir and all of its content should also be readable (r-x). To achieve that you could use these commands:

```
# cd example
# find . -type d | xargs chmod 755
# find . -type f | xargs chmod 644
```

(doing this does not make files executable as sudo chmod -R 755 /Users/nickcorin/webserver does)

b. Upstream troubleshooting. Check that firewall (if any) is ok with your upstream php { server 127.0.0.1:9000; }

**Note1**. "Welcome to Nginx" html document usually stored in /usr/share/ that has required grants.

**Note2**. It's better to use some location in your system which you'll create and set all required access permissions manually for your environment rather then use user directories which come with 700 permission (and cause some additional step to setup permissions related stuff).

**Note3**. Remember that `403 Forbidden` is also responded when we have no index file in a directory.

Comment: Wow! Thanks for the answer! :D

1. My index.php contains a phpinfo() echo already.
2. My error.log only contains entries of the nginx signal started.

This should point towards a permission error like you said, I used `ps aux | grep nginx` and 'root' handled the nginx master process but 'nobody' handled the worker process. I will attempt the permission change though! Thank you so much for the answer.

On the third note, I did see this - I have an index.php present in the website root and have turned autoindexing on just in case.

Comment: Running the chmod commands didn't change anything, I have a feeling it has to do with the users and groups. 'Nobody' handles the nginx process. When I right click the 'example' folder and click get info it says that 'nickcorin' can read/write, staff can read and everybody can read. That's it.

Comment: It will be more easier to find and fix problems if you fix file permissions for **error_log** and its directory. I guess that if worker processes are running under 'nobody' user there might be issues with logging. But I am not sure. You have to check permissions /var/log/nginx or wherever nginx logs are stored. If you want to get stuff working instantly - you're free to set 777 on nginx logs directory. But if you want to understand, what exactly is happened, then check if there are any issues with logging! :) Try to post some `ls -la` listings of nginx logs folder.

Comment: Thanks @A.Efremov! I have listed some of my terminal outputs in the question. I don't think I'm fully understanding the permissions and ownership concept.

Comment: So, turns out I ended up fixing my error. I searched through every web tutorial I could find and edited my server config file. I'm not exactly sure how it fixed my errors, but this is the way I will configure my virtual hosts in the future. Thank you for all your help :) I will post my config file in the question.